How can I fit sklearn.svm.SVC with three features, given that the features are actually arrays of lengths 128, 12 and 40?
To clarify, each instance of feature_1 is a 128 item long array, each instance of feature_2 is a 12 item long array, and each instance of feature_3 is a 40 item long array. I am currently simply doing model.fit(x_train, y_train) without doing anything to the arrays. As a result, I am getting the error: 'ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence'. The arrays themselves are entirely made of decimal numbers.
I've since tried to use padding to equalize array lengths. I've padded everything to a size of 128. I'm still getting the same error when I try training the SVC.

The direct way is to treat each element as a single feature.
Doing so will give you 128+12+40 = 180 features.
Depending on your current data-structure numpy.concatenate might come in handy.
Note that 180 features can lead to the curse of dimensionality (especially when there are few samples). In that case you might want to perform some feature selection.

I think there are a few ways one could approach this.
The best course of action depends on the nature of the data and task, as well as experimentation. If you could speak more to what the features represent, and the modelling goal, I might be able to provide suggestions that are more specific.
Stack the features
The simplest is to stack the columns of each feature into one wide array:
all_features = np.column_stack([features_1, features_2, features_3])

The shape of all_features would be (n_samples, 128 + 12 + 40), i.e. (n_samples, 180).
The upside is that it's a simple approach. You end up with 180 features going into the model, which might be an issue if your dataset is too small.
Stack projected features
A variation on this is to first project each feature down to a smaller representation using PCA() or more expressive sklearn.manifold methods. For example:
features_1_projected = manifold.MDS(n_components=64).fit_transform(features_1)

This would represent features_1 using half as many features. If you repeat this for each feature, you can stack the projected features into a single array. It should carry much of the same information as the first method, but in a smaller dimensionality. Cross-validation could be used to select between different projection methods and configurations.
Neural nets could also be used in a similar way, with the benefit that the projection they learn directly optimises for predictive performance.
Train separate models
It might be worth trying to train 3 separate models, one for each feature set. You'd then ensemble their results using a majority vote, averaging, or suchlike available in sklearn.ensemble. Each model works with fewer features, which helps manage over-fitting. But if the features are inter-dependent, then the models might significantly underfit.
In practice, this method may be more useful for descriptive modelling (understanding the predictive contribution of each feature set independently) rather than predictive modelling.
